# mongodb: Query documents with average greater than a number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I find the documents with with average score greater than 5. The collection looks like this:
Collection restaurants:

```
{"grades": [{"grade": "A", "score": 2}, {"grade": "A", "score": 6}], "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop", "restaurant_id": "30075445"}

{"grades": [{"grade": "A", "score": 8}, {"grade": "B", "score": 23}], "name": "Wendy'S", "restaurant_id": "30112340"}

{"grades": [{"grade": "A", "score": 2}, {"grade": "A", "score": 11}], "name": "Dj Reynolds Pub And Restaurant", "restaurant_id": "30191841"}
```

I tried

```
db.restaurants.find({average_socre: {$gt: 5}}, {average_socre:{$avg: "$grades.score"}})
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this query:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        "$avg": "$grades.score"
      },
      5
    ]
  }
},
{
  average_score: {
    $avg: "$grades.score"
  }
})
```

[Live](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SWLYp3caL1j)